# Threshold Bitcoin signature scheme

Tags: multiparty-computation, schnorr-signature

Any advice would be appreciated:

It seems to me that using an uncomplicated combination of a shamir scheme and schnorr it's fairly trivial to have a threshold signature scheme.

I think it's also easier than other scheme's I've read about, and also probably more secure.

Is there some reason this construction doesn't work?

Summary:

1. M participants roll a random "share" (private key)
2. Interpolation in the exponent of public keys to produce combined public key
3. Signing of a message M is done using Schnorr on each "share"
4. Signatures are combined using Shamir interpolation
5. Verification via standard Schnorr

Long winded description:

https://medium.com/@simulx/an-m-of-n-bitcoin-multisig-scheme-e7860ab34e7f

Comment: Two rounds of Shamir scheme would produce a Schnorr signature.